# jlink showing error while comparing hashes

Tags: javafx, jlink

I am currently trying to bundle a javaFx test application via maven and jlink into a runtime image. I am using bellsoft liberica 18.0.1 as a jdk and I am running on a IntelliJ IDE. I have used the IDE to setup the project initially (via the wizard). If I hit javafx:run, everything fires up correctly, the application is displayed and all is fine.

However, running javafx:jlink produces the following error:

> Error: Hash of javafx.base
> (d775513043c11c457939b41e544cc7a83a4076454da4a0798bdc6922ec7d3f8f)
> differs to expected hash
> (eb1d4f72b292e9bf33005b36c4afeda11b66a8745b868bf0593d1cd4c2974681)
> recorded in java.base java.lang.module.FindException: Hash of
> javafx.base
> (d775513043c11c457939b41e544cc7a83a4076454da4a0798bdc6922ec7d3f8f)
> differs to expected hash
> (eb1d4f72b292e9bf33005b36c4afeda11b66a8745b868bf0593d1cd4c2974681)
> recorded in java.base

This appears odd, as I am unsure which hashes are compared at that point. I have tried executing jlink with --fail-never as well as --lax-checksums and ignoreSigningInformation, but nothing appears to help. I have also tried to check the sha-checksums from within my m2-Repository, but I can't nail it down that way either.

Any help to sort this out is much appreciated.

EDIT: Including the current pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>myappMavenModulebased</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
        <version>11.5.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.synedra</groupId>
        <artifactId>validatorfx</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
        <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
        <version>12.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
        <artifactId>medusa</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.test.myapp.AppLauncher</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>18</source>
                <target>18</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.test.myapp/com.test.myapp.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                        <launcher>app</launcher>
                        <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                        <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                        <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                        <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                        <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        <failNever>true</failNever>
                        <ignoreSigningInformation>true</ignoreSigningInformation>
                      <jlinkExecutable>/home/user/.jdks/bellsoft-jdk19.0.1/bin/jlink</jlinkExecutable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

EDIT 2: I am providing the jlink-Tool in the pom.xml. My idea was that doing it this way, jlink would be able to create the runtime image based on the liberica-jdk. Is the problem that I am using openjfx-dependencies with the liberica-jlink-Tool?

Comment: Try setting your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I have set the JAVA_HOME to the bellsoft liberica jdk mentioned above, the platform sdk in the IDE is set there too. However, the error still persists.

Comment: Can you maybe explain what exactly you mean by this? Why is JAVA_HOME relevant, as I have specified the jlink version to be used in the pom-File (jLinkExecutable). Which checksums is jlink trying to compare anyhow?

Comment: Have you tried some other and non-outdated Java/FX distribution?

Comment: I suggested setting `JAVA_HOME` because the [javafx-maven-plugin may use it](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/blob/b63e0367a1e29d205f937c0c276c03d08557df4a/src/main/java/org/openjfx/JavaFXBaseMojo.java#L528).  I don’t recall exactly what the plugin uses it for.  I think it will use it to find the jlink tool if you don’t provide a path to it. But it may use it for other reasons, such as locating modules in the JDK.  Best to have it correctly set to eliminate a potential source of error (my opinion).

Comment: Which liberica version are you using?  Is it the “Full JDK” version which includes JavaFX modules?  If so, are you also specifying JavaFX modules in Maven dependencies or VM or tool execution parameters?  And if so, could those be clashing with what it prepacked with Liberica? Please edit the question to add a complete pom.xml that replicates the issue and a download link or instructions for the JDK you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What the problem is**

The module hash mismatch when using jlink occurs because:

1. You use Liberica "Full JDK" which includes pre-built JavaFX modules in a jmod format AND
2. You *also* define JavaFX dependencies in your Maven project based on JavaFX modules in jar format.

This confuses the linker, resulting in the mismatched hash error.

- The linker knows there are two copies of the same module with the same module version available on the module path, but they have different hashes, so it errors and exits.
- It would be more useful if the error told you exactly where the two modules with differing hashes were found (you could create an [enhancement request](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) with the jlink tool in the JDK for that, referencing this post, if you wanted).

**How to fix this**

You can fix this by either:

1. Use a JDK distribution that does not include pre-built JavaFX modules (e.g. a standard OpenJDK download or a Liberica "Standard JDK" version) OR
2. Remove the JavaFX dependencies from your pom.xml file.

**Getting some link debug info**

To debug, in the pom.xml file configuration for the javafx-maven-plugin, add:

```
<jlinkVerbose>true</jlinkVerbose>
```

This will tell you where jlink sourced the modules from (when jlink works).

You can also run maven in debug mode (`--debug` command line switch for `mvn`).  Maven will tell you a lot more information. For example, the actual full command line and option set used to invoke jlink.

Here is a debug line for linking using OpenJDK using maven jar dependencies for the JavaFX modules:

```
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [/Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/jlink, --module-path, /Users/myusername/dev/linktest/target/classes:/Users/myusername/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/19/javafx-base-19-mac.jar:/Users/myusername/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/19/javafx-controls-19-mac.jar:/Users/myusername/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/19/javafx-fxml-19-mac.jar:/Users/myusername/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/19/javafx-graphics-19-mac.jar, --add-modules, com.example.linktest, --output, /Users/myusername/dev/linktest/target/app, --strip-debug, --compress, 0, --no-header-files, --no-man-pages, --verbose, --launcher, app=com.example.linktest/com.example.linktest.HelloApplication]
```

The command line text can be useful because you can copy it and link from the command line prompt rather than from within Maven (just for testing and verification purposes).

**Linking using liberica "Full JDK" which includes JavaFX jmods**

For your pom.xml with these changes:

- `jlinkExecutable` in the javafx-maven-plugin configuration set to the jlink in my liberica location.

  - I don't think this is necessary if the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is properly configured to match the liberica distribution and the mvn tool is invoked using the liberica distribution.
- `jlinkVerbose` in the javafx-maven-plugin configuration set to true.
- all JavaFX dependencies commented out.
- project module and package name changed to `com.example.linktest`.

  - I just did that because that is what I used to create the project, as long as the name is consistent everywhere, it doesn't matter what it is.

And a minimal `module-info.java` to generate a basic JavaFX FXML application added. The linker will output:

```
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.8:jlink (default-cli) @ myapp ---
com.example.linktest file:///Users/myusername/dev/linktest/target/classes/
java.base file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-19.0.1/jmods/java.base.jmod
java.datatransfer file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-19.0.1/jmods/java.datatransfer.jmod
java.desktop file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-19.0.1/jmods/java.desktop.jmod
java.prefs file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-19.0.1/jmods/java.prefs.jmod
java.scripting file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-19.0.1/jmods/java.scripting.jmod
java.xml file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-19.0.1/jmods/java.xml.jmod
javafx.base file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-19.0.1/jmods/javafx.base.jmod
javafx.controls file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-19.0.1/jmods/javafx.controls.jmod
javafx.fxml file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-19.0.1/jmods/javafx.fxml.jmod
javafx.graphics file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-19.0.1/jmods/javafx.graphics.jmod
jdk.unsupported file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-19.0.1/jmods/jdk.unsupported.jmod
```

All of the JavaFX dependencies are sourced from the liberica provided jmods, such as this:

```
liberica-19.0.1/jmods/javafx.base.jmod
```

**Linking using OpenJDK and JavaFX maven jars**

If instead you use a standard OpenJDK without pre-built JavaFX modules and JavaFX modules added as dependencies in the pom.xml, then the output is:

```
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.8:jlink (default-cli) @ myapp ---
com.example.linktest file:///Users/myusername/dev/linktest/target/classes/
java.base file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home/jmods/java.base.jmod
java.datatransfer file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home/jmods/java.datatransfer.jmod
java.desktop file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home/jmods/java.desktop.jmod
java.prefs file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home/jmods/java.prefs.jmod
java.scripting file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home/jmods/java.scripting.jmod
java.xml file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home/jmods/java.xml.jmod
javafx.base file:///Users/myusername/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/19/javafx-base-19-mac.jar
javafx.controls file:///Users/myusername/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/19/javafx-controls-19-mac.jar
javafx.fxml file:///Users/myusername/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/19/javafx-fxml-19-mac.jar
javafx.graphics file:///Users/myusername/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/19/javafx-graphics-19-mac.jar
jdk.unsupported file:///Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home/jmods/jdk.unsupported.jmod
```

The javafx modules are sourced as jars out of the .m2 repository rather than coming as mods from the JDK:

```
.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/19/javafx-base-19-mac.jar
```

Either way, you end up with a packaged, linked, usable JavaFX application.

Comment: Hi jewelsea, many thanks for the detailed instructions. I had to tinker around with my java versions a bit more, because maven was using jdk 11 still. Setting the JAVA_HOME as environment variable for maven helped me to overcome a major/minor version error. Packaging with jlink now works! Many thansk again.